# Serial port doesn't work if i will not mark it as static

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am opening a serial communication as the example below:

```
public class ModemSerialPort
{
    public ModemSerialPort(string serialPort)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialPort))
        {
            var mySerialPort = new SerialPort(serialPort);
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            mySerialPort.Open();

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += MySerialPort_DataReceived;
        }
    }
```

and inside my form

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var modemInit = new ModemSerialPort("COM1");
}
```

The example above doesn't work

Only if i will mark SerialPort as static.

```
public class ModemSerialPort
{

 private static SerialPort mySerialPort;

 public ModemSerialPort(string serialPort)
 {

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialPort))
    {
       mySerialPort = new SerialPort(serialPort);
       ////
     }
  }
```

Why is this happen? Does the gc collector clearing my class? after on load event will end?

Also Is there any difference if i will use public static method inside my class instead default constructor? Example

```
public class ModemSerialPort
{
  public static void ModemInit(string serialPort)
  {

  }
}
```

And inside OnLoad Method

```
ModemSerialPort.ModemInit("COM1");
```

Comment: You are not saving you object `ModemSerialPort` anywhere... you will create new object, assign it to a variable `modemInit`, but than method `Main_Load` will end and variable modemInit is lost. Same thing is with the class... Youi are not storing the variable anywhere..

Comment: Thank you  Vojtěch Mráz. So using static method is the right way?

Comment: Is there any difference if i will use public static method inside my class? Example public public static ModemInit(string serialPort). and inside OnLoad Method ModemSerialPort.ModemInit("COM1");

Comment: It depends, what are you trying to do. Static means that variable will be stored in general for all objects `ModemSerialPort`. But for example if you want to open more than one serialport in your program, than it will not work and you will store only the last one opened.

Comment: I will write longer answer to your question

Comment: Thank you  Vojtěch Mráz. Please explain me also if there is difference with second method in as i wrote in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, i can see that you are little bit confused with the what `static` means and how to use it. For that, I recommend you to read this article in microsoft documentation: [Static Classes and Static Class Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

You can say, that class is somehow "template" or "skeleton" for your objects. That means, if you have class `Person` with attributtes `Name` and `Age`, you can always create new object `new Person()` and set the attributtes as you want. After that you will have multiple different objects with different attributtes `Name` and `Age`. But if you say, that this class is static: `public static class Person`, that means that you cant create object from it and there will be only one instance in whole program.

Same thing is here with your problem. But it depends on the purpose of your application. If you want to open only one serialPort and not using any others. Than I would recommend to use something like this:

```
public static class ModemSerialPort
{
  public static SerialPort OpenedSerialPort;

  public static void ModemInit(string serialPort)
  {
    ...
    OpenedSerialPort = new SerialPort()
    ...
  }
}
```

And you will have only one instance of this static class and you can call like `ModemSerialPort.ModemInit("COM3")` for example... and after init, you can use opened serial port under `ModemSerialPort.OpenedSerialPort`.

If you want to open more than one serial ports, you cant use static class or static methods.

```
public class ModemSerialPort
{
  public SerialPort OpenedSerialPort;

  public void ModemInit(string serialPort)
  {
    ...
    OpenedSerialPort = new SerialPort()
    ...
  }
}
```

But here, you need to first cerate an object `var modem = new ModemSerialPort()` and than Init it `modem.ModemInit("COM3")` and than you will have your opened serialport under `modem.OpenedSerialPort`... BUT!!

In your `Main_Load` method, you have to store `modem` variable somewhere, otherwise after `Main_Load` method is done, every reference to not anymore used variables will be lost and GC will eventually dispose this object.

I hope, this will help...

Comment: Thank you  Vojtěch Mráz. Indeed! I need to create only one SerialPort in my whole  project and i want to prevent accidentally someone to call ModemSerialPort.ModemInit("COM3") method twice.